# What's the different between Termux and Linux Arm64?

Tags: linux, termux

I have try a lot of Android Application for install linux in Android. Such as Termux, Linux Deploy, AndroNix, AnLinux Aix Learning and so on...

I can't understand what's different with those virtual Linux? And what's the different with Linux Arm64 and those virtual Linux?

Can I copy a bin file from a Linux Arm64 machine to Termux and run it directly?

For example, after root, I can use luks in Termux. But I can't use luks in Ubuntu which installed by AndroNix successful. Why?

Forgive my poor English.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, You cant get a whole Ubuntu like system in android and you android is already a Linux system. After you became root in android you can access everything that is in core Linux i.e Kernel. If you are willing to use Linux desktop install it on your computer and Enjoy..